# Wrong Animation Playing on Mouse Click

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator

Specifically, when I press the left mouse button, the undocking animation replays instead of the attack1 animation. I've using alternate methods but nothing's working so far, unless there's a way to do it some other way that I haven't tried yet, using Animation or AnimationClip. I'm pretty new to Unity so any help would be great. Also, if anyone knows why the conditions for the idle animation aren't activating as well, that'd be super helpful, thanks anyone who can help.

```
{

    [Range(10, 200)]
    public float triggerDistance;
    private bool attacking;
    public Animator attack1;
    //public MovementScript movementScript;
    public Animator tenticleAnimationDocking;
    public Animator tenticleAnimationUndocking;
    public Animator idle;
    public Transform centre;
    public Transform missileOrigin;
    private bool dockingAnimationPlaying;
    private bool undockingAnimationPlaying;
    private bool attackAnimationPlaying;

    void Start()
    {
        tenticleAnimationDocking = GetComponent<Animator>();
        tenticleAnimationUndocking = GetComponent<Animator>();
        idle = GetComponent<Animator>();
        attack1 = GetComponent<Animator>();
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //movementScript = GetComponent<MovementScript>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (attacking)
            Attacking();

        if (Vector3.Distance(centre.position, missileOrigin.position) < triggerDistance) {
            tenticleAnimationUndocking.Play("Undocking");
            undockingAnimationPlaying = true;

        }else{

            undockingAnimationPlaying = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Attacking();
            attackAnimationPlaying = true;

        }else{

            attackAnimationPlaying = false;
        }

      if (Vector3.Distance(centre.position, missileOrigin.position) < triggerDistance)

        if (dockingAnimationPlaying == false)

          if (undockingAnimationPlaying == false)

            if (attackAnimationPlaying == false)

            {
            idle.Play("Idle");
            }

        if (EnemySpawn.totalMissileCount >= 40) {
            Reattach();
            dockingAnimationPlaying = true;

        }else{

            dockingAnimationPlaying = false;
        }
    }

    private void Reattach()
    {
        tenticleAnimationDocking.Play("Docking");
    }

    private void Attacking()
    {
        CheckAnimation();
        attack1.Play("Attacking");
    }

    private void CheckAnimation()
    {
        if (attacking)
        {
            attacking = false;
        }
        else
        {
            attacking = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope so this will help take some time and read this. [https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112143/when-to-use-a-blend-tree-vs-state-machine-for-animation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112143/when-to-use-a-blend-tree-vs-state-machine-for-animation)

Comment: Could it be that `attacking == false`? There's nothing other than `CheckAnimation` that show us where you set `attacking`. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: No, turned out that the trigger distance was setting off the undocking animation instead of the attack animation because there was nothing to check and stop the undocking from playing again once in range. Anyway, all fixed now.